# Defining Mac OS X workspaces with macros

Tags: macos, spaces, workspace

When I'm at home I use an external monitor with my MBP; when I'm on the road I don't have access to this. I therefore have two separate workspace setups.

Does anyone know of a macro or similar that would set these workspaces up for me? I waste quite a bit of time setting them up by hand.

Answer (score 2):

You might like to provide a bit more information on what you'd expect this macro to do.

However, [Optimal Layout](http://most-advantageous.com/optimal-layout/), an app I developed, allows you to quickly select a group of windows to fill the screen and move them between Spaces.

Comment: Thanks! I'll certainly check out Optimal Layout.

Essentially, I'd expect the macro to open a number of programs in OSX and then place the windows for those programs in specific Spaces. That's it, really; I'm sure it would be pretty straightforward to achieve in AppleScript, but I'm pushed for time and wondered if a script already existed somewhere on the net.